# Slow upload speed with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, django, iis

I have an interesting problem - I have my own IIS 2016 server, that I use to host a website which allows the users to upload a variety of files - some in text format, the others zip'ed up together. Initially the website would return error 500 from the server when trying to upload something bigger, like ~50MB. I Googled up that IIS requires configuration of maxAllowedContentLength (changed default to 209715200, ~300MB) and FastCGI's parameters for IDLE, ACTIVITY and REQUEST (changed to 600) in order to allow bigger files upload without hitting the file size limit. However, now that the files are getting uploaded, the upload speed for these bigger files slowed down to a crawl. Previously I could upload ~20MB files in 10sec on a local network, while now 50MB takes like ~160sec. Not a linear increase I would expect.

My website runs on Django, and my POST method file transfer is carried out by Ajax call in JS:

```
$('#sn').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

var post_data = new FormData($("#sn")[0]);

$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
      var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
        var percent = Math.round(evt.loaded/evt.total * 100)
        console.log(percent)
        $('#query_button').attr('disabled', true)
        $('#query_button').get(0).innerText = "Upload status: " + percent + '%'
      }, false);

      xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
        $('#query_button').get(0).innerText = "PLEASE WAIT..."
      }, false);

      return xhr;
    },
    url: '#',
    type: "POST",
    data: post_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    statusCode: {
      200: function() {
      // alert("Server received request and posted a response!");
      },
      404: function() {
        alert("Error code 404: Page not found!");
      },
      408: function() {
        alert("Error code 408: Request Timeout!");
      },
      500: function() {
        alert("Error code 500: Internal server error!");
      }
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response) 
    }
  });
})
```

Can anybody please tell me, if the Ajax call could be the culprit of this slow-down in upload speed, or if it is something else that needs to be adjusted on IIS?

Comment: do 20MB still take only 10 seconds? and are you on the same "local network"?

Comment: I have just tried ~11MB upload with the current settings, and the upload took 7.76sec according to Chrome's Network->XHR->Timing tab. According to the same tab for the 50MB upload, it took 2.8min.

Comment: Yes, the server is on the same network as my laptop I am connecting to it from.

Comment: What I meant was, nothing else has changed - i.e. you haven't changed the network, or which network you're dealing with ... only thing you changed was to allow bigger files ...

Comment: That is correct - nothing other than the config of FastCGI and IIS's maxAllowedContentLength parameter has changed.

Comment: Um, I am not an expert on Servers, as you can probably tell - can you give me an example of how I can get you this information?

Comment: Ah yes, that bit is taken care of by Django - the form upload via POST method results in the files being saved in the media folder of the Django project. No IIS handling is involved on this front.

Comment: OK, will remove my "noise" from the comments :p

Comment: there are some "upload" settings you can tweak in django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#file-upload-settings ... increasing `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` (default 2.5MB) could be the key